# What are the six beads at the end of a mala used for? And what is there meaning if there is one

Tags: meditation

I recently received a Impermanence Mala for Christmas.  I have read The Heart of Buddha's teaching and I couldn't find anything in there.

Thank you in advance for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your tradition and the design of your mala, they're for counting cycles (if they can be slid around the tassels/cords), representing the Triple Gemn and/or Six Perfections, or just decoration.